# Find the number of positive and negative words in a text using a Lexicon,

Tags: python, nlp, nested-lists, sentiment-analysis, lexicon

I am trying to figure out how to create a lists of lists where each sublist contains the number of positive words and negative words in a given text. Below I have the names of the positive and negative text files that I am working with and an example of the words in those text files. Also an example text in the 'X_train' variable. And what the output should look like.

---

***positive_words.txt # happy, great, amazing***

***negative_words.txt = # sad, bad, poor***

***X_train = ['the food was great and service was amazing', 'i was happy with my food', 'my food tasted bad', 'i am poor and could not buy the food so i am sad but least i have chicken']***

***X_train_lexicon_features = ?***

---

**How the output of the above variable should look.**

```
print(X_train_lexicon_features)
```

**OUTPUT:
[[2,0], [1,0], [0,1], [0,2]]**

**# From the example given above, the first text in the X_train variable should yield [2,0] since it has 'great' and 'amazing' which are both in the positive_lexicon. [positive,negative]**

---

Below is a class to count the number of positive and negative words.

```
class LexiconClassifier():
    def __init__(self):
        self.positive_words = set()
        with open('positive-words.txt', encoding = 'utf-8') as iFile:
            for row in iFile:
                self.positive_words.add(row.strip())

        self.negative_words = set()
        with open('negative-words.txt', encoding='iso-8859-1') as iFile:
            for row in iFile:
                self.negative_words.add(row.strip())
    
    def count_pos_words(self, sentence):
        num_pos_words = 0
        for word in sentence.lower().split():
            if word in self.positive_words:
                num_pos_words += 1
        return num_pos_words

    def count_neg_words(self, sentence):
        num_neg_words = 0
        for word in sentence.lower().split():
            if word in self.negative_words:
                num_neg_words += 1
        return num_neg_words
```

---

Here is the code I have run to return the number of positive words per text.

```
myLC = LexiconClassifier()

X_train_lexicon_features = []

for i in X_train:
     X_train_lexicon_features.append(myLC.count_pos_words(i))
```

**OUTPUT:
[2,1,0,0]**

What I am unsure of is how to mix in the 'count_neg_words' function into the code above that will also return a lists of lists like so: **[[2,0], [1,0], [0,1], [0,2]]**.

I appreciate any advice and **thank you** in advance!